# Group by column , get mean of another column, return max

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
exam_data = {'name': ['Anastasia', 'Dima', 'Katherine', 'James', 'Emily', 'Michael', 'Matthew', 'Laura', 'Kevin', 'Jonas'],
'score': [12.5, 9, 16.5, np.nan, 9, 20, 14.5, np.nan, 8, 19],
'attempts': [1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1],
'qualify': ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes']}
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

I want to write a function to group by one column, get the average for each category, and then return the highest average

The current way I did this

```
avg = df.groupby('attempts')['score'].mean() 
print(avg.max())
```

I want to write something like this

```
def return_max_average(df, category_column, numerical_column): 
  avg = df.groupby('category_column')['numerical_column'].mean() 
  return avg.max()
```

What would be the best way to write this function?

Comment: So you just want the max value, nothing else about the group? Your function seems fine, except you want to use the variables not the strings: `avg = df.groupby(category_column)[numerical_column].mean()` so they reference the actual variable you pass, not those static strings

Comment: The function does what you expect it to, but you're looking for a better way?

Comment: That seems like an OK way to do what you're after. You'll want to use the function arguments rather than hardcoded strings in the first line of your function.